# How to prove that $L=\{0^m1^n\;|\; \mathbf{gcd}(m,n)=1\}$ is not regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

The [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) is allowed to be used in this assignment, so I have tried to make $|0^{m+b|y|-|y|}| = |xy^b| = a!, a\ge |y|,a\ge n$ so that $gcd(|0^{m+b|y|-|y|}|,n) \neq 1$.

Comment: Okay. What difficulties are you having? What are you asking us to do? Please clarify and remember that this isn't a do-my-work-for-me site.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like homework so I will just give a high level idea. The idea behind the pumping lemma is that regular languages are so structured that any long enough word in the language has a sub-word that you can “pump” as many times as desired without exiting the language. In your case, we want to use this to show that your language is not regular, and therefore we should find a long enough word in the language that doesn’t allow for pumping.

Let’s think of examples of long words in the language.

Example 1) $0^m 1$, for a large $m$. Can you take a subword of this and pump it without exiting the language? Yes, just take a subword consisting only of 0s.

Example 2) Let $p$ be a large prime, and consider the word $0^p1^{p+1}$. Why is this word in the language? Prove that no matter what subword you choose, if you pump it the right amount of times the result will exit the language. Here you can proceed by cases; what if the chosen subword has only 0s, what if has only 1s, and what if it has a mixture of both.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the pumping lemma, you can prove directly that a finite state machine cannot work.

Assume you have a state machine with k states. And you just parsed 0^p 1 for some prime. So you are in a state where n*p-1 1s will get you to an accepting state. After parsing a 1, you are in a state where parsing n*p-2 1s gets you to an accepting state. That state must be different. And every 1 you parse gets you to another state that must be different from the others, until you parsed p+1 1s and are back in the first state.

So you need at least p states. If p > k then your state machine with k states cannot parse it. That’s true for any finite state machine and any number of states. Therefore the language is not regular.